# How to get apex to save my checkbox?

Tags: apex

How to get this line to save the field to true?
"cpgsnew.Record_Was_Cloned__c = True;"

If I try `update` or `upsert cpgsnew` I get an error "DML Currently not allowed"

Below is my controller

```
public class vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr {


    //Set up variables and lists

    public List<Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c> listGoalsCurrYear {get;set;}
    public List<Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c> listGoalsPrevYears {get;set;}
    public String ft { get; set; }
    public String ccp { get; set; }
    public String fa { get; set; }
    public String fd { get; set; }
    public String ga { get; set; }
    public String gac { get; set; }    
    public String newRow {get;set;}
    public Boolean showMsg {get;set;}

    public String currentYear = String.valueOf(System.Today().year()) ; 
    public String parentID;


    //Variable to hold add records to be deleted
    public List<Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c> deleteList = new List<Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c>();

    public vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {    
        //Show warning that one must click on save/update button to save changes
        showMsg = False;
        ApexPages.Message myMsgShowSaveInfo = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsgShowSaveInfo);
        listGoalsCurrYear = new Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c[]{};
            listGoalsPrevYears = new Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c[]{};    
                parentID = controller.getID();
        // get all records for all years        
        for(Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c cpgs : [ SELECT id,Year__c,Funding_Type__c,Funding_Amount__c,Funding_Description__c,Funding_Comments__c,
                                                   Core_Current_Participation__c,
                                                   Goal_Amount__c,Goal_Amount_Comments__c,Community_Plan__c,Name,EditableOrReadOnly__c,Funding_Type_Description__c,Record_Was_Cloned__c 
                                                   FROM Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c
                                                   WHERE Community_Plan__r.id = :parentID
                                                   ORDER BY Year__c]){
                                                       // add all records to currYear section (top) which is editable

                                                       if(cpgs.Year__c == currentYear) // Get current years goals
                                                       { 
                                                           listGoalsCurrYear.add(cpgs);
                                                       }
                                                       else if (Integer.valueOf(cpgs.Year__c) == Integer.valueOf(currentYear)-1) // Only show last years goals not older
                                                       {
                                                           listGoalsPrevYears.add(cpgs);
                                                       }

                                                   }

        // Add how ever many previous years rows to the current year
        if (!listGoalsPrevYears.isEmpty())
        {
            for (Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c cpgsnew : listGoalsPrevYears)
            {
                if (cpgsnew.Record_Was_Cloned__c<>True) 
                {
                    // Flag record as cloned so it won't be cloned again
                    cpgsnew.Record_Was_Cloned__c = True;

                    AddRowForPreviousYearsData(cpgsnew.Funding_Type__c,cpgsnew.Core_Current_Participation__c,cpgsnew.Funding_Description__c,cpgsnew.Funding_Comments__c, cpgsnew.Funding_Type_Description__c);                    

                }
            }

        }

    }

    public Void AddRowForPreviousYearsData(String fundingType, String  coreCurrentParticipation, String fundingDescription, String fundingComments, String description)
    {

           Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c cpgs = new Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c(year__c = String.valueOf(System.Today().year()), Community_Plan__c = parentID,Funding_Type__c=fundingType,Core_Current_Participation__c=coreCurrentParticipation,Funding_Description__c=fundingDescription,Funding_Comments__c=fundingComments,Funding_Type_Description__c=description);

            //This next line allowes fields to be displayed in edit mode for new records
            if( cpgs.year__c == String.valueOf(System.Today().year()) ) newRow = 'nr';        

            listGoalsCurrYear.add(cpgs);

        //        return null;
    }

    public pageReference AddRow()
    {
        // Create new record for each row
        Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c cpgs = new Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c(year__c = String.valueOf(System.Today().year()), Community_Plan__c = parentID);

        //This next line allows fields to be displayed in edit mode for new records
        if( cpgs.year__c == String.valueOf(System.Today().year()) ) newRow = 'nr';        

        listGoalsCurrYear.add(cpgs);

        return null;
    }

    public pageReference SaveRecords()
    {
        ApexPages.Message myMsgSuccess = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Your changes were saved.');  
        showMsg = True;
        //Save the list of records
        try {
            upsert listGoalsCurrYear;   

            // Show feedback
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsgSuccess);

        } catch (exception e)
        {

        }
        // Delete records if necessary
        if(deleteList.size()>0 && deleteList <> NULL)
        {
            delete deleteList;
        }


        return null;    
    }

    //Remove a record from the table.
    public pageReference removeRecord(){
        Integer indexVal = Integer.valueof(system.currentpagereference().getparameters().get('index'));

        //If existing then add it to the list to delete from the database
        if(listGoalsCurrYear[indexVal - 1].Id != null) deleteList.add(listGoalsCurrYear[indexVal - 1]);

        //Remove row from the table    
        listGoalsCurrYear.remove(indexVal - 1);   

        return null;
    }    

}
```

Comment: You are getting this error because DML statements from Constructor are not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DML is not allowed in controller constructors, if you really need to do so you can do so using an on load action, as discussed on the [Developer Forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000952VIAQ):

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="controllerWithDML" action = "{!dmlOperation}">
</apex>
```

Controller:

```
public class controllerWithDML {
     public PageReference dmlOperation() {
          ...
     }
}
```

If your controller is being used by a Visualforce component, you will also need to include the 'AllowDML=true' attribute on the component tag:

```
<apex:component controller="componentController" AllowDML="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because DML statements from Constructor are not allowed.

- change the constructor to method returning PageRefernce and return null from this method.
- Add action attribute in VF page's  tag. i.e

`<apex:page controller="vf_CommunityPlanGoalPSetting_Cntrlr" action="{!yourAction}" > ... </apex:page>`